# replicate d3 indented tree to ms word using phpdocx

Tags: php, d3.js, phpdocx

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Hi, we can used to above link for reference as you can see it is an indented tree in d3. What i want to do is to replicate that tree in ms word using phpdocx. Here is what i have tried so far. I'm using a text with a border to replicate the rectangle in d3 and a line. I want my LINE at the back of my TEXT so that i can replicate the d3 indented tree.  I used the position: absolute and z-index in the line but stil i have problem layouting my TEXT AND LINE to phpdocx i wish i can an image of what i have so far i dont have enough privelege to do so
below code is what i have so far

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();

 $array = array('young girl rape our young girls but violeta gave willingly gosh shes nervous','young girl rape our young girls but violeta gave willingly gosh shes nervous','young girl rape our young girls but violeta gave willingly gosh shes nervous','young girl rape our young girls but violeta gave willingly gosh shes nervous');


$a = ($k * 10) + 10;
$b = ($k * 10) + 60;

$options = array('points' => "$a,$a $a,$b $b,$b",
'strokecolor' => '#ff00ff',
'strokeweight' => '2',
'position' => 'absolute',
'fillcolor' => 'none',
'z-index' => -500
);
$docx->addShape('polyline', $options);

foreach($array as $k => $v){



$indentLeft = $k * 250;
$paragraphOptions = array( 'border' => 'single',
                            'position' => 'absolute',
                            'borderColor' => 'b70000',
                            'borderWidth' => 12,
                            'backgroundColor' => '#F4F4F4',
                            'indentLeft' => $indentLeft,
                            'spacingBottom' => 50,
                            'fontSize' => 10,

                            );

$docx->addText($v, $paragraphOptions);



}



$docx->createDocx('example_addTextBox_1');  

?>
```